# property 'row' not found on object of type 'NSIndexPath *' in iOS tableview

Tags: ios, sqlite, tableview, nsindexpath, rowid

I tried to fetch row id of an item with the help of "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" in iOS.
Code:

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  

      indexPathRow=indexPath.row;  

      self.recordIdToEdit = [[[deviceNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];  
      NSLog(@"Item selected..%d", self.recordIdToEdit);  

     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController" sender:nil];  

  }
```

While debugging i get following error for po :

```
 (lldb) po [deviceNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  
 error: property 'row' not found on object of type 'NSIndexPath *'  
 error: 1 errors parsing expression  
 (lldb) po indexPathRow  
 <nil>
```

What's going wrong here?  deviceNameArray is an array of string that contains result fetched from sqlite db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this while debugging we need to send int value

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{  

         int index=indexPath.row;  

          self.recordIdToEdit = [[deviceNameArray objectAtIndex:index]];  
          NSLog(@"Item selected..%d", self.recordIdToEdit);  

         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController" sender:nil];  

      }
```

Comment: Yes, I have messed it up with string values objects instead of int

Answer (score 3):

Just `@import UIKit;` in your .h file and you'll be fine.

Comment: Worked for me but I thought NSIndexPath is declared in Foundation?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference I just got this error and it had nothing to do with `indexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//...
   Task *task = [self.tasks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//...
    return cell;
}
```

My error was that `self.tasks` was populated with `NSDictionary`s instead of Task objects.

So, at least in my case the error was misleading, if nothing else is working maybe check the type assignment.